# Error using pagination in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have a pagination problem in CodeIgniter:
My routes are:

```
$route['tv/bloc']                     = "tv/about";
$route['tv/bloc/page/(:any)']        = "tv/about";
$route['tv/bloc/(:any)']              = "tv/view/$1";
```

In my controller:

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url()."tv/bloc/page/";
$config["total_rows"] = $this->site_tv->record_count();
$config["per_page"] = 24;
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;
$choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config ["num_links"] = round($choice);
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4))? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
```

The pagination works fine for pages 2,3, and 4 of pagination but when I want to return to the first page of pagination I get an error because the controller is trying to search url the /page...

Is there a solution to help me solve my problem?

Comment: Please give the URLs generated for page 1 and page2

Answer (score 0):

Set firstpage's URL manualy:

```
$config['first_url'] = 'tv/bloc/page/1'; 
// Your code..
$config["base_url"] = base_url()."tv/bloc/page/";
$config["total_rows"] = $this->site_tv->record_count();
//  ....
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep this snippet saved for any future use:

```
    $paging_config = array();
    $paging_config["base_url"] = site_url() . '/p/';
    $paging_config["total_rows"] = $this->qosasah_model->snippets_count();
    $paging_config["per_page"] = 10;
    $paging_config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $paging_config['use_page_numbers']  = FALSE;

    /* This Application Must Be Used With BootStrap 3 *  */
    $paging_config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-right'>";
    $paging_config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
    $paging_config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $paging_config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $paging_config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $paging_config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $paging_config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $paging_config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';       
    $paging_config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $paging_config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $paging_config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $paging_config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $paging_config['first_link'] = 'First';     
    $paging_config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $paging_config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $paging_config['last_link'] = 'Last';       
    $paging_config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $paging_config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
```

Note: This works perfectly with bootstrap 3. So, if you're not using bootstrap, you can simply remove the unwanted configurations.